# Creating an event handler for user right clicking and inspecting an element in Firefox or Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

This is probably a question motivated more by concern for privacy than the potential for applicability, but is there a way to create an event handler that picks up the event of the user right clicking and selecting "inspect element" in Chrome or Firefox?

If there's not clear answer for this, is there a way to handle events for right click menu selections?

Comment: Chrome Developer Tools can be opened by pressing Ctrl+Shift+I or from the Settings menu, so you are out of luck in any case.

Answer (score 2):

a fiddle I put together, you can get all the information on the element that the `mousedown`
event was on

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);

document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    console.log(e); // you can inspect the click event

    $this = $('.cmenu');

    if (e.which === 3){ // right click = 3, left click = 1
        $this.addClass('open');
        $this.css({
            'left': e.pageX - $this.width() / 2,
            'top': e.pageY - $this.height()
        });
    }else if(e.which === 1 && e.target.nodeName == "HTML"){
        $this.removeClass('open');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MKBdv/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to event `click`, add check whether it is right click:

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    console.log(e); // you can inspect the click event

    if (e.which === 3) { // right click = 3, left click = 1
        alert("right click");
    }
});

// prevent context menu show up
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Comment: I'm aware of listening for any click events that happens within the page's markup but I have yet to find a way of listening for events within the right click menu.

Comment: @Emanegux i think there is no way to listen events within the context menu refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305220/identifying-getting-selected-contextmenu-item-in-javascript