# Javascript: Detect left click on an opened contextual menu

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to detect a left click on the contextual menu to no avail, my script should update a div on change, keyup or copy from the contextual menu in a textarea. 
This is what I've tried:

```
$("#keywords").bind("click keyup change", function(){}
$("#keywords").bind("contextmenu keyup change", function(){}
```

Both the codes above need an extra click on the page to fill the DIV.

Is there any solution to this?

Thx

Comment: Also, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault might be a key-word to search a helpful information, if I were you.

Comment: @KenOKABE, that just won't work because it prevents the contextual menu from opening, I want it to open and the user to left click on "paste" and the DIV should update after that last click. Sorry if I'm missing something, I'm a beginner trying to learn by working on a project.

Comment: Pretty sure it's impossible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305220/identifying-getting-selected-contextmenu-item-in-javascript

Comment: Fair, is there a way to detect right click followed by left click and firing the code after the second click?

Comment: Please narrow what do you want to achieve here? Is it to prevent paste? Or to prevent all contextual menu from right click?@CreekBarbara

Comment: None, I want the function to fire when the user right-clik the textarea and then left click (preferably, on the "paste" line whitin the contextual menu, but apparently it's impossible) . @HariSetiawan

Comment: What is it that you *really* want to do? This is clearly a XY problem. Maybe you are actually just looking to use the "input" event rather than "keyup"?

Comment: Exactly. Thank you @IngoBürk that's exactly what I was trying to do. I didn't even know that it exists :) Thank you again.

Comment: I've added an answer for it. Please mark it as accepted (and consider upvoting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot detect anything regarding the context menu since this happens outside the context of the page itself.

You can either use the `paste` event, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/paste), or, if you just want to track any kind of changes to the textarea, just use the `input` event:

```
$("#keywords").on("input", function() { ...};
```

Answer (score -1):

Not clear enough. Try something like:

```
$(document).on('change keyup', '#keywords', function(e){
   //Do something when typing/changed like update the div html
  $('.my-div').html($(e.target).val());
});
```

Comment: The keyup part is working, my concern is the left click on contextual menu. You have to right click to open it an then  left click to click on "paste" and it's that part that I want to trigger. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think there isn't away to detect a left click on the contextual menu. I would prevent it from opening and create a custom one instead.

Comment: Ok thank you. Is there a way to detect right click followed by left click and firing the code after the second click?