# js event if user clicks on browser's context menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to `slideUp` `nav` element if user uses browser's contexmenu and clicks on `Open link in a new tab` option?

```js
$('.title').on('click', function(){
  $('.nav').slideDown();
});

$('.nav').on('click', function(){
  $(this).slideUp();
});
```

```css
.title{cursor:pointer;}
.nav{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title'>MENU</div>
<div class='nav'>
<a href = 'https://google.com'>Google</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identifying/Getting selected contextmenu item in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305220/identifying-getting-selected-contextmenu-item-in-javascript)

Comment: You can listen for when the built-in contextmenu is *displayed* - but not for when an item on the contextmenu is *clicked*.  See duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, a context menu does not give you, your 100% accepted answer, you can stop the element right click show context menu. you show that a custom menu code here, maybe it helps you. link: http://jsfiddle.net/6cqhsfvL/1/ or above code

```js
$('.title').on('click', function(){
   $('.nav').slideDown();
 });

 $('.nav').on('click', function(){
  $(this).slideUp();
 });

 $('.nav a').on("mousedown",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if(event.which==3){
   $('#item li a').attr('href', $(this).attr('href'));
  }
 });

 $('.nav a').bind("contextmenu",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  $("#cntnr").css("left",e.pageX);
  $("#cntnr").css("top",e.pageY);     
  $("#cntnr").fadeIn(200,startFocusOut());    
 });
    $("#items").on('click', 'a', function(event) {
     event.stopPropagation();
     $('.nav').slideUp();
     $("#cntnr").hide(); 
     window.open($(this).attr('href'), '_blank'  );
    });

 function startFocusOut(){
   $(document).on("click",function(){
   $("#cntnr").hide();        
   $(document).off("click");
   });
 }
```

```css
.title{cursor:pointer;}
.nav{display:none;}

#items{
  list-style:none;
  margin:0px;
  margin-top:4px;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
  padding-bottom:3px;
  font-size:17px;
  color: #333333;
}
#cntnr{
  display:none;
  position:fixed;
  border:1px solid #B2B2B2;
  width:150px;      background:#F9F9F9;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #E9E9E9;
  border-radius:4px;
}
li{
  padding: 3px;
  padding-left:10px;
}
#items :hover{
   color: white;
  background:#284570;
  border-radius:2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class='title'>MENU</div>
 <div class='nav'>
 <a href = 'https://google.com'>Google</a>
 </div>

 <div id='cntnr'>
     <ul id='items'>
      <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Open new tab</a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
```